# In a game of bridge with a deck of 52 cards, Determine the probability of having a hand containing exactly 4 kings, 4 queens, and 5 hearts?

Tags: probability, card-games

In my attempt i'm not sure if i am under counting by having 13C2 instead of 13C1 and 12C1. Thanks.

My attempt:

[(13C2)(4C4)(4C4)(11C5)(4C1)]/52C13.

Comment: Could you give us a little more of an idea of where you came up with the formula in your attempt?

Comment: Your answer seems to be on the right track, but the 13C2 and 4C1 shouldn't be there.

Comment: my idea was there are 13 different denominations so choose 2 to cover the fact that i want a king and queen. There are 4 kings and 4 queens and i want 4 kings and 4 queens so choose 4 and 4. there are 11 reminder denominations and i don't care what i get so Choose 5. However, i want 1 specific suit out of 4 so choose 1.

Comment: @fastforwards I think what's confusing here is the use of the term "choice" in these contexts. Note for instance, a factor of 4C1 would be appropriate if we are trying to count possiblities that use any of the 4 possible suits. This factor would come up if we were counting hands where the remaining 5 cards were all of the same suit, but not necessarily hearts. However, since it is given in this context that we are sticking to the suit of hearts, there is only 1 "choice" of suit in our consideration.

Answer (score 0):

As you have correctly determined, the denominator must be ${}_{52}C_{13}$. In the numerator, we need the total number of hands that satisfy the requirement of having 4 kings, 4 queens, and 5 hearts.

In this case, the task is easier than you seem to be making it. In particular, there are exactly 4 kings and 4 queens in the deck, which means that the number of ways to select these 8 cards is $1$.

Now, we need the number of ways in which we can select the $5$ hearts that form the remainder of the hand.  Since we have removed the kings and queens, there are $11$ hearts to choose from. Thus, the total number of ways that we can select $5$ such hearts is $_{11}C_{5}$.

Thus, number in the numerator should be $1 \cdot {}_{11}C_5 = {}_{11}C_5.$

Comment: Since among all the kings and all the queens we already definitely have two hearts, we only need three more hearts.

Comment: @zipirovich It depends on how you interpret the question statement. I assumed that "and $5$ hearts" means "and $5$ other hearts", so that the total number of cards in the hand is $13$. If $5$ refers to the total number of hearts in the hand, however, then you are correct.

Comment: The way I read it, it says "exactly ... five hearts". I agree that it's a bit ambiguous, though.